# Script to unzip a file geodatabase fails with Memory Leak

Tags: python, arcgis-10.2, file-geodatabase

Hijacked the ESRI script to unzip. After research I found there is a memory leak. There are three zip files I download on a regular basis. Each .zip contains one (1) .gdb. 
The largest is 2 GB zipped, and 6 GB .gdb. I'm running Windows 7 64 bit, with 32 GB RAM. ArcGIS 10.2.2 and python 2.7 (32 bit on win 32)
What is interesting is the leak will reset itself with each zip.namelist(). Meaning I will end up with all three .gdb's I need, but their contents will not be complete.

```
#**********************************************************************
# Description:
#    Unzips the contents of a zip file into an existing folder.
# Arguments:
#  0 - Input zip file
#  1 - Input folder - path to existing folder that will contain
#      the contents of the zip file.
#**********************************************************************

# Import modules and create the geoprocessor
#
import sys, zipfile, arcpy, os, traceback
from os.path import isdir, join, normpath, split

# Function to unzipping the contents of the zip file
#
pathz = "C:/HEP/Data"
os.chdir(pathz)

mylist = os.listdir(pathz)
for z in mylist:
    if z.endswith('.zip'):
        print z
        def unzip(path, zip):
            # If the output location does not yet exist, create it
            #
            if not isdir(path):
                os.makedirs(path)

            for each in zip.namelist():
                print "Attempting unzip"
                arcpy.AddMessage("Extracting " + os.path.basename(each) + " ...")

                # Check to see if the item was written to the zip file with an
                # archive name that includes a parent directory. If it does, create
                # the parent folder in the output workspace and then write the file,
                # otherwise, just write the file to the workspace.
                #
                if not each.endswith('/'):
                    print "Splitting files"
                    root, name = split(each)
                    directory = normpath(join(path, root))
                    if not isdir(directory):
                        os.makedirs(directory)
                    print "Writing files"
                    file(join(directory, name), 'wb').write(zip.read(each))
                    print "Successful Unzip"

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            try:
                # Get the tool parameter values
                #
                infile = z
                outfol = pathz

                # Create the zipfile handle for reading and unzip it
                #
                print "Trying to Unizp"
                zip = zipfile.ZipFile(infile, 'r')
                print "Zip understood"
                unzip(outfol, zip)
                zip.close()

            except:
                # Return any Python specific errors and any error returned by the geoprocessor
                #
                print "Error"
                tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
                tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
                pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback Info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n    " + \
                        str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"
                arcpy.AddError(pymsg)

                msgs = "GP ERRORS:\n" + arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n"
                arcpy.AddError(msgs)
```

Comment: As an update, I can easily extract the GDB from the zip file using windows explorer and everything works fine. Trying to do it with python.

Comment: I copied your script, ran it and it worked for me...

Comment: Thank you Hornbydd. At least now I know its in the files. I created a fake gdb, zipped it, and ran the script and it too ran fine. Now my guess is a permissions issue on one of the files in the zipped gdb.

Comment: Upon inspection of the fake .gdb and the subject .gdb, I noticed the above script is not copying the gdb or the timestamps file.

Comment: Turns out this is an exceptions.MemoryError. These File Geodatabases are GB in size. Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: It would probably be better if you edit your question, using the edit button at the bottom left, to add any additional details rather than a long trail of comments. Are you using 64bit background processing? How many GBs in size? If you're only using 32 bit processing then the file (or some file component of the gdb) may be too large to address. Since it works in Windows Explorer, that would suggest physical memory available isn't the issue.